error ng is not defined en prueba automatizada
Haciendo una prueba automatizada con Cypress me explota el siguiente error en consola

ng is not defined

Ya intente ignorar el error pero simplemente la prueba no continua, este error solamente ocurre al hacer las pruebas en Cypress con Edge o Chrome, en Electron no explota el error, pero si uso algun navegador fuera de cypress el error nunca explota
